# Processing data before saving to database Django Tastypie

Tags: django, timestamp, tastypie, type-conversion

I send a string to the server and I want to convert it to a Timestamp before saving in the database.

I want to do this function before saving the data.

```
date = time.strptime(date, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

date is sent as a string and I want to convert it to a TIMESTAMP before saving in database.

Thank you for your help.

```
#models.py
from tastypie.utils.timezone import now
from django.db import models
from django.utils.text import slugify


class Entry(models.Model):
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField()
    Temperature = models.FloatField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

---

```
#api.py
from tastypie import fields
from tastypie.resources import ModelResource
from models import Entry
from tastypie.authorization import Authorization 

class EntryResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = Entry.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'entry'
        authorization = Authorization()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the hydrate method on your resource.

```
class EntryResource(ModelResource):


    def hydrate(self, bundle):

        if  field in bundle.data:
                    date = bundle.data['pub_date']
                    bundle.data['pub_date'] =  time.strptime(date, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

        return bundle
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer but where I put this function ? in models.py or api.py which this function: class EntryResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = Entry.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'entry'
        authorization = Authorization()

Comment: api.py.  It is a method on your EntryResource class.

Comment: It doesn't work. I updated my answer whith my entire code. Can you tell me exactly all the code ?. In my api.py I did : from tastypie import fields
from tastypie.resources import ModelResource
from models import Entry
import time
from tastypie.authorization import Authorization 

class EntryResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = Entry.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'entry'
        authorization = Authorization() 
        
    def hydrate(self, bundle):
        bundle.data[Entry.pub_date] =  time.strptime(Entry.pub_date, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

        return bundle

Comment: use bundle.data['pub_date']

Comment: get it from the same field in the bundle. date = bundle.data['pub_date']

Comment: ? I saw my changed didn't accepted to your post I edited. You answer was ok but I did 3 changed for working.. the last version : def hydrate(self, bundle):
        if  fields in bundle.data:
                    date = bundle.data['pub_date']
                    bundle.data['pub_date'] =  date.strptime(date, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

        return bundle

Comment: Sorry but I can't vote because I a new.. I need more reputation to be able to vote.